# JS Array map returning empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, knex.js

I'm trying to use map to return a new field at an array of objects and once i do it returns empty.

Expected result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "awesome stadium",
        "opened": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "capacity": "39590.00",
        "location": "some awesome",
        "team_id": "147ff48e",
        "team": {
            "name": "some name",
            "location": "some location"
        }
    }
]
```

Code:

```
    const venues = await connection(VENUE_TABLE)
      .limit(LIMIT_PER_PAGE)
      .offset((page - 1) * LIMIT_PER_PAGE)
      .select('*');

    const venuesWithTeam = venues.map(async (element) => ({
      ...element,
      team: await connection('team')
        .where('id', element.team_id)
        .select('*')
        .first(),
    }));

    return response.json(venuesWithTeam);
```

What could i do to make it work as expected?

Comment: `venuesWithTeam` will be an array of Promises - it's not empty - it's only empty because you're trying to convert a Promise to JSON - which results in nothing

Comment: try `const venuesWithTeam = await Promise.all(venues.map .... etc)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`async` functions always return a Promise, but `.map` does not "await" these promises (it just put them "as is" in the result). If you want to get all the results, the simplest way would be [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const venuesWithTeam = await Promise.all(venues.map(async (element) => ({
  ...element,
  team: await connection('team')
    .where('id', element.team_id)
    .select('*')
    .first(),
})));
```

Note: this will start running all the operations in parallel (simultaneously) and wait for all of them to be resolved before continuing. If `venues` is a very large array, it could cause a large number of connections to your database and potentially cause some issues.

To run the requests one after the other, you will have to loop and wait for the previous one to be resolved. One way to do that can be done using `reduce`.

```
const venuesWithTeam = await venues.reduce((prom, element) => (
  prom.then(async result => (
    result.concat({
      ...element,
      team: await connection('team')
        .where('id', element.team_id)
        .select('*')
        .first(),
    })
  ))
), Promise.resolve([]));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked for me. Since the first one runs the operations in parallel i prefered to use the second.

Comment: I keep forgetting that map can't with the await thing I just keep forgetting

Answer (score 1):

venues.map will return an array of Promises. Promises don't stringify to JSON - well, they do, to `{}`

So, you must await all the promises returned by .map in your code

so, `Promise.all(x.map( ..... ))`

i.e.

```
const venuesWithTeam = await Promise.all(venues.map(async(element) => ({
  ...element,
  team: await connection('team')
    .where('id', element.team_id)
    .select('*')
    .first(),
})));

return response.json(venuesWithTeam);
```

Or, to run each iteration in series rather than parallel

```
const venuesWithTeam = [];
for (element of venues) {
  venuesWithTeam.push({
    ...element,
    team: await connection('team')
      .where('id', element.team_id)
      .select('*')
      .first(),
  });
}
return response.json(venuesWithTeam);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Promise.All` in your code.

```
const venuesWithTeam = await Promise.all(venues.map(async (element) => ({
  ...element,
  team: await connection('team')
    .where('id', element.team_id)
    .select('*')
    .first(),
})));
```

Comment: you made venuesWithTeam a function that will return a Promise - this is as broken as the question

Comment: @JaromandaX oh, yes. I missed that. I've edited. Please check now.

Comment: yep, that's the code I suggested in the comment, and posted as an answer